# Start (or resume) a driver for an app on the foreground without launching the app?

Tags: python, android, selenium, automated-tests, appium

I'm trying to emulate 2 actions on a Genymotion emulator using Appium:

1. Go to a specific URL, the website then redirects to the Google Play Store.
2. Press "INSTALL" on that Google Play Store screen.

I have managed to get the URL, but when I try to start a driver for the Google Play app, it relaunches the app, which I don't want. I need to emulate a click on the INSTALL button right after I get redirected to Google Play. I have looked into running parallel tests, but it seem to launch the app for every test.

This is my code. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_caps_web = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    platformVersion='8',
    deviceName='Google Pixel',
    automationName='UiAutomator1',
    browserName='Chrome',
    chromedriverExecutable='C:\\Users\\Khoa_Ngo\\node_modules\\appium-chromedriver\\chromedriver\\win\\chromedriver.exe')

driver_web = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps_web)

driver_web.get('https://someURL.com')

desired_caps_vending = dict(
    platformName='Android',
    platformVersion='8',
    deviceName='Google Pixel',
    automationName='UiAutomator1',
    app='/Users/Khoa_Ngo/Google Play Store.apk',  #This is bit of a workaround because I kept running into problems about intent action.
    appPackage='com.android.vending',
    )

driver_vending = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps_vending)

driver_vending.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'install')]").click() #Not working
```

Also how should I emulate the click (last line in code block)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add capability autoLaunch=false to desired capabilities.

autoLaunch  Initializing the app under test automatically. Appium does not install/launch the app under test if this is false. Defaults to true

Description from: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#android-only